# Scheduling a stored procedure in PostgreSQL 9.2.8

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I've a simple stored procedure which calculates values from 1 table and insert it in another. I want to schedule it to run once in a day.

I came across [`pg_cron`](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) but it looks like it will only work for version 9.5 and above.

How to to schedule this sp or it;s select statement `select * from stored_procedure_name()` in postgres

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have built-in scheduler, unfortunately. Use `cron` instead.

Comment: can I use it with 9.2.8 ?

Comment: `Cron` is just a scheduler in Unix-like systems. It is independent of PostgreSQL. So, yes, any scheduler will do.

Comment: [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgagent.php)? Pretty sure this was around long before 9.2.

Comment: @NickBarnes have to do it through linux command line so I assume cron is the only option

Comment: Why isn't an upgrade an option? 9.2 will be out of support in 5 months so you need to plan an upgrade anyway

Comment: I can't do an upgrade right in the middle of an ongoing project. It is in the pipeline but till than have to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as mentioned by @AlexM I started looking in Cron and found few useful links to do this outside of postgresql.

[crontab in linux with 20 useful examples](https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/) helps me out in understanding the structure for creating a new entry in the crontab.

edit the crontab file and added the following entry in it. As it's in the same server so no need to pass credentials for the postgresql

```
00    00    *     *    * psql -c "select query here;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the previous comments are correct.  There is no scheduler within PostgreSQL nor any of the supplied utilities.  Your only option is to use an external scheduler.

Comment: There is indeed no built-in scheduler. But there are extensions that achieve this. e.g.: https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron (however that requires a  more up-to-date version then 9.2)

Comment: Ok a_horse_with_no_name, I happen to like the citus contributions also.   My point still stands that this is an external scheduler, and one among many.