# Automatic execution of SQL query in Postgres

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am here asking if there is a solution to execute a SQL query in Postgres automatically (every one hour for example)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheduling a stored procedure in PostgreSQL 9.2.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43382874/scheduling-a-stored-procedure-in-postgresql-9-2-8)

Comment: I have searched about the problem and i have found this article https://sqlbackupandftp.com/blog/postgresql-job-scheduler

Comment: If the answers to that linked question and the article you've found are not sufficient to solve your problem, please can you edit your question to add details of your operational requirements? For example, if `cron` is not an option for you it would be useful to explain why (it's important to show that it's a unique question, not a duplicate).

Comment: I have not used it, but you may want to look into the recently released (as in earlier this week) [pg_dbms_job](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/pg_dbms_job-v120-released-2435/). If it works as advertised it gives Postgres the much needed0, long awaited scheduler.